# Promises not working as expected with async.each

Tags: node.js, promise, async.js

I'm somehow not able to find the solution. Here is what I'm doing:

```
    async.each(bottles, function(bottle) {
        // set substance quantity to 0
        updateQuantity(bottle[constant.SUBSTANCE_ID], 0)
            .then(function() {
                bottle[constant.EXPIRY] = expiry;
                bottle[constant.IS_AVAILABLE] = true;

                updateRecord(bottle)
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('Updated');
                    },
                    function() {});
            }, function() {});
    }, function() {
        console.log('Finished');
    });
    console.log('Done');
```

The method updateQuantity and updateRecord returns promises and are using Knex update in the background which also returns a promise. 
I want the output of the above code to be:

```
Updated
Updated
Finished
Done
```

But the output I'm getting is:

```
Done
Updated
Updated
```

So, the callback of **async.each** is not working and the code is not waiting for **async.each** to finish.

Comment: `async.js` *does* not work with promises. Don't use it.

Comment: Why are you using those no-op functions ?

Comment: @Bergi Any suggestions other than async.js?

Comment: @Ashutosh check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the passed in `callback` from the `async.each` operation. As it is, async doesnt know when your callback resolves.

Also, `DONE` should always be the first text you see as `async.each` doesn't block. When you start running running the script, `async.each` will be registered, but because your code is asynchronous it will reach the `console.log('Done')` before the `updateRecord` and `updateQuantities` complete

```
async.each(bottles, function(bottle, callback) {
    updateQuantity(bottle[constant.SUBSTANCE_ID], 0)
        .then(function() {
            ...

            updateRecord(bottle)
                .then(function() {
                    console.log('Updated');
                    callback();
                },
                function() {});
        }, function() {});
}, function() {
    console.log('Finished');
});
console.log('Done');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot megawac, just confirmed your answer in the docs as well :)

Comment: This does not handle failures.

Comment: OP asks for the correct usage of `async.each` with promises. Sure treating failures appropriately is part of that.

Comment: OP asked what the issue was and for its solution, not for how to properly handle error states and control flows which are well covered in the async docs.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use async.js at all with promises, they are capable of what you need with their builtin methods and you don't need to fall back to callbacks.

```
bottles.reduce(function(prev, bottle) {
    return prev.then(function() {
        // set substance quantity to 0
        return updateQuantity(bottle[constant.SUBSTANCE_ID], 0)
    }).then(function() {
        bottle[constant.EXPIRY] = expiry;
        bottle[constant.IS_AVAILABLE] = true;
        return updateRecord(bottle);
    }).then(function() {
        console.log('Updated');
    });
}, Promise.resolve()).then(function() {
    console.log('Finished successfully');
}, function(err) {
    console.error(err)
}).then(function() {
    console.log('Done'); // notice you must put this in the callback
});
console.log('Started');
```